# use requestImageDataForAsset method shows virtual memory exhausted

Tags: ios, memory, photo-gallery

When I use **requestImageDataForAsset**:  to store some data, and there are over 10,000 photos in my camera roll,  and I have already add @**autoreleasepool** for **requestImageDataForAsset**: but when I run **requestImageDataForAsset** method again, app

---

Crash
and shows this error: 
**Error : libBacktraceRecording.dylib: allocate_free_list_pages() -- virtual memory exhausted!**

```
for (PHAsset *asset in albumResult){ //there are over 10000 photos

                    if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeImage) {
                        __block NSString *orgFilename = nil;
                      @autoreleasepool {
                        [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
                         requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                         options:imageRequestOptions
                         resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                         UIImageOrientation orientation,
                                         NSDictionary *info)
                         {
                             if ([info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]) {
                                 NSString *photoURL = [[info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]absoluteString];
                                 orgFilename = [[photoURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
                    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"type",@"title",@"status",@"res_resURL",@"path",@"shareName",@"authtok",@"nasIp",@"macAddr",@"albumName",nil];
                    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"assetID",orgFilename,@"queue",asset.localIdentifier,destinationPath,shareName,authToken,nasIp,macAddr,albumName, nil];
                    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
                    [scanedData addObject:dict];
                             }
                         }];
                       }
        }
```

why dose @autoreleasepool not release memory?
I checked the used memory in xCode debug navigator it always shows around 130MB, seems autorelease pool dose not do its job?!